# Computing the maximum power that this opamp provides to the load Rl without occurring distortion

Tags: circuit-analysis

Here's the schematic:

[image]

So first stage is a differential amplifier where vo1 =3.72V in DC (Vin= 0). In this stage i can say AmplVo1 = gainStage1 * AmplVi where distortion only happens when vo1 is bigger than Vcc (Vcc = 8V) or when T6 hits saturation.

The first case is when Vcc - VoDc = 8-3.72 =4.28 V , this is a critical point. I can imagine a sine wave with a DC component of 3.72 where its amplitude doesn't surpass 4.28 V (limit).

With T6 i dont really think it is necessary do show work because it wont affect anything, the amplitude of v01 will be bigger than the computed above.

My problem is what i should do with the next 2 stages. I remember my teacher saying to compute the DC voltage from the emissor T2 and subtract that from the DC voltage of Vo1 but i'm not sure what to do with that.

Comment: How can anyone help without values? The diff amp's linearity depends on the emitter degeneration resistors, but is highly nonlinear except over a small excursion if those resistors are zero. You haven't defined your level of acceptable distortion. Etc. Need more info.

Comment: Duplicate of https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/500530/trying-to-compute-the-power-that-the-operational-amplifier-provides-to-a-load